# Customizing Edit button in UITableview

Tags: iphone, uitableview

Can we customize the edit button as we customize the delete button in tableview.

``[image]

As you see in pic the edit button is in red colored circle, I need to customize the this button is it possible.

Comment: Which button do you want to customize, the red "Delete" button to the right or the red circle to the left?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make your customize UITableViewCell with your own images. And then perform Animation on Edit & Done clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible with the default delegates and datasource and methods. you need to draw in your own view. Make a custom table view cell, override -touchesBegan:withEvent:, and check for touches. Calculate the delta of the two touches (in touchesMoved:withEvent:) and move your own view around.

Comment: Yes you are right we should use custom tablecell. Even I am using the same. As you can see in my above Pic delete button is my custom Image. I need to do same custom edit button which you can see at left side