# Override the setEdit method in UITableview

Tags: iphone, uitableview

Can we override the functionality of setEdit method in UITableview. If Yes (can we change it behavior such as images and animation effect etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can take custom class which inherits from UITableView, and you can put your own logic in setEdit method.

Comment: ok cool to hear it, can we change the color of edit button (circled one). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6537095/customizing-edit-button-in-uitableview

Comment: I am trying from past two day to change the color or image of edit Button. If you have done it please guide me how to achieve it.

Comment: do you want to change entire image or want to change style of button? Use this to change style of button  - (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

Comment: @ Jignesh Brahmkhatri i want to change the image in circle one.